# Unable to get the actual remaining time from rate limiter

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, rate-limiting

I've created a rate limiter for login which limits the request to `n` times per 10 minutes. If a request has reach the rate limit, I want to return a validation exception informing the remaining time before the rate limiter is cleared.

For simplicity, I set the limit to just `2`, as follows:

```php
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
    $email = (string) $request->email;
    $throttle_key = str($email)->ascii()->lower().'|'.$request->ip();

    return Limit::perMinutes(10, 2)
            ->by($throttle_key)
            ->response(function () use ($throttle_key) {
                $seconds = RateLimiter::availableIn($throttle_key);

                throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                    'email' => trans('auth.throttle', [
                        'seconds' => $seconds
                    ]),
                ]);
            });
});
```

The code above is limiting the request correctly: users only has 2 attempts within 10 minutes to try to login using their email. However, the `RateLimiter::availableIn($throttle_key)` is not giving the correct value as I mentioned above.

When I tried to login incorrectly for the 3rd time, instead of getting the value between 1 to 600 seconds remaining, the `RateLimiter::availableIn($throttle_key)` only gives 1-60. After passing the 1st minute of the decay time, it always showing `0` second remains, but the rate limiter is still holding the request as it should for the next 9 minutes.

Please share any suggestion that comes to your mind. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the same problem, but I tinkered around and In the `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter` class where the facade is coming from did some dumps,

Apparently it is storing it in the cache with some weird names, for example my key was `'1'` and it had stored it in a cryptographic manner something like `'sdkf34kfshsf:timer'` in the cache, and accessing it via the method `availableIn` was passing just `'1'` to the cache and not the encrypted value.

A workaround I have found is to use the value from the header to calculate the remaining time.

In the callback function of the response method add the headers array.

```
->response(function(Request $request,array $headers) {
```

and in the 'seconds' line

```
'seconds' => $headers['Retry-After']
```

OR

```
'seconds' => $headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'] - time()
```

the difference should provide the seconds remaining

Comment: hi @francisco, sorry for the really-late response. I've been working on something else for the last couple months. I just tried your solution and it works! Some questions though: (1) which one should I use, the `Retry-After` or `X-Ratelimit-Reset`? does the two of them is just the same or one is actually giving more accurate data? (2) Does it mean I can safely replace `RateLimiter::availableIn()` with the above or should I combine them somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Both Retry-After and X-RateLimit-Reset headers can be used to implement rate limiting for login requests. The `Retry-After` response HTTP header indicates how long the user agent should wait before making a follow-up request;
while `X-RateLimit-Reset ` header indicate the timestamp when the current window ends; after this timestamp, the rate limit resets to the value in `X-RateLimit-Limit`.

Comment: Use the tools you have it's better than to workaround, so check more the [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiting/Limit.html) if you find something different.